# UIWindow remove error in iOS9.1

Tags: ios, uiwindow, ios9.1

In iOS9.1, When I remove a custom UIWindow by removeFromSuperView and set to nil, it did't disappear automatically until click on the window. and  show error with

> unexpected nil window in _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent,
>   _windowServerHitTestWindow: (null)

When in iOS9 and lower,it will works fine.

```
UIWindow *window = [target associatedValueForKey:lock_window];
if (window) [window removeFromSuperview];
[target associateValue:nil withKey:lock_window];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has solved the problem with code

```
UIWindow *window = [target associatedValueForKey:lock_window];
if (window) [window removeFromSuperview];
window.hidden = YES;
[target associateValue:nil withKey:lock_window];
```

the `- (void)makeKeyAndVisible` method annotation is

> convenience. most apps call this to show the main window and also make it key. otherwise use view **hidden property**